# SQL: Export multiple variables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I set multiple variables and try to export all variables.

My code is as the following:  (error: Incorrect syntax)

```
Declare @TableA_count int
Set @TableA_count = (Select count(*) from tableA)

Declare @TableB_count int
Set @TableB_count = (Select count(*) from tableB)

Select TableA_count,TableB_count
```

Question: The code works in SQL Server Management Studio.  I get an error message when I export them to MS Excel 365:

> [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Syntax error in query expression '(Select count(*) from tableA)'.

Comment: Define export? Print, just prints to a screen, your normally return results using `select`.

Comment: *Print (TableA_count,TableB_count)* this is a syntax error, whether you remember `@` or not; At the very least you need `select` not `print`.

Comment: Hi Dale. It works with the following code: select TableA_count,TableB_count. 

I get an error message when I export them to MS Excel 365 . Error message is "[Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Syntax error in query expression '(Select count(*) from tableA)'."

Comment: I don't know anything about Excel 365 does it have some facility to link to SQL Server and  embed a query? You need to provide as much information as possible in your question because non of us know the details of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi Dark, John Cappelletti real want to help people and provide solution for it.

Comment: Hi Dale, You do not know Excel 365 is not the reason you close the question

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps another way of looking at it

```
Select *
 From  (values ('TableA',(Select count(*) from tableA))
              ,('TableB',(Select count(*) from tableB))
       )V(TableName,RowCnt)
```

**Sample Results**

```
TableName   RowCnt
TableA      3210552
TableB      11017449
```

**As Columns**

```
Select (Select count(*) from tableA) as tableA
      ,(Select count(*) from tableB) as tableB
```

**As a String**

```
Select concat(
              (Select count(*) from tableA)
             ,'   '
             ,(Select count(*) from tableB)
             ) as AString
```

Comment: Hi John, Can we have export as the format: RowCnt      3210552 11017449?

Comment: @Anson you need to use the correct terminology, this isn't an export, this is just data retrieval.

Comment: Hi Dale, my original question is export multiple variable. John provide different solution., so the question may change to data retrieval

Comment: @Anson if you are exporting data then you must be using a different tool, which you haven't explained. If you have your own export tool, then the question still relates to data retrieval. So you need to be clear about exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Anson I presented an alternative because I assumed you wanted a data object for consumption.   In all my years I've used PRINT less than a dozen times, and not ONCE as part of a production environment.    You say EXPORT, that is an ambiguous term at best.

Comment: @Anson I added a couple of alternatives.

Comment: @John your solution: Select (Select count(*) from tableA) as tableA
      ,(Select count(*) from tableB) as tableB is good (I can run it in ms sql server management studio) . I get an error message when I export them to MS Excel 365 . Error message is "[Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] Syntax error in query expression '(Select count(*) from tableA)'."

Comment: Hi Dale, Do you have a solution and try to help people, not just close the question you cannot answer?

Comment: @Anson I want to be very clear here.  Dale was correct in closing this question.  As stated, there is no answer.  The question lacks details and is ambiguous at best.  That said, I made an assumption and offered a possible alternative.   Now, as of 25 minutes ago, it turns out your target is Excel.   There are many folks here (including Dale) who want to help, but the responsibility of asking a clear and concise question is on you.    I learned a long time ago that communication is everything.

Comment: Hi John, Dale is different from you. You try to provide solution to help people. However, Dale does not offer any valuable solution for it. Thank you for your answer

Comment: @Anson  Take a peek at https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk00_wRMycxY7zt9MpIdOYJb_cWYlJA%3A1629242388957&lei=FEQcYZ_sOfbA0PEPpoGnOA&q=office%20365%20excel%20connect%20to%20sql%20server&ved=2ahUKEwifxuLumLnyAhV2IDQIHabACQcQsKwBKAB6BAhGEAE&biw=1920&bih=1009

Answer (score 0):

The PRINT command only displays output messages to the SQL Message tab (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/print-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

If you're trying to output the counts from Table A & B, then SELECT the values from both tables...

```
Declare @TableA_count INT
Set @TableA_count = (Select count(*) from tableA)

Declare @TableB_count INT
Set @TableB_count = (Select count(*) from tableB)

SELECT @TableA_count, @TableB_count
```

Comment: No need for 2 selects though.